# Is there a bug in Pycharm's expand recursively function

Tags: pycharm

I'm aware that the obvious solution to this problem is to post it in `https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com` but I did that 4 days ago and did not receive a reply.  Generally, they only reply to extremely important posts.  I was wondering if someone else could verify that their expand recursively function is not working, which command-option [plus] sign.  When I hit those buttons the font on my Pycharm increases. The option button on my computer is definitely working, because command option C brings up recent changes in Pycharm which is what is supposed to happen.  Moreover, you can assign your own shortcuts on Pycharm and I tried that in the preferences for the expand recursively function.  So I assigned option tilde to expand recursively but that activated the expand all function and I'm positive that I did not hit the wrong button.

Also, I have the latest pycharm installed - 2017.3, released a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there are these + and - signs on the gutter of the app where if you press them it will expand or collapse the whole function.  So that is a sufficient work around, perhaps even better.